# Is there a way to format JLabel to show numbers with powers?

Tags: java, jlabel

is there a way to format jLabel text to show a number with power index?

For example I would like a label to show 2^2 as 2² or x^2 as x²

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JLabel support HTML, you can use HTML to show x²  as follow:

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("<html>x<sup>2</sup></html>");
```